# One time use coupon code

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I need to generate 500 unique codes for coupons.
I have two steps.

1: generate 500 unique codes a coupon and to be used.

2: manage using these coupons.

First, is there a plugin to do that? If not, how can I implement it?

Comment: You can Use this plugin for generate Bulk coupon https://wordpress.org/plugins/coupon-generator-for-woocommerce/.If you need any document for this please check this url https://shopplugins.com/bulk-generate-coupons-woocommerce/

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow* - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/coupon-generator-for-woocommerce/

> is a coupon generator that allows you to setup and generator tens of thousands of coupons at the same time.
>
> By going through 3 easy steps you can setup your desired coupons and start generating the coupons.
>
> **Generation process**
>   Step 0) Introduction, ‘how to’
>
> Step 1) Select coupon settings
>
> Step 2) Select generation settings
>
> Step 3) Coupons are being generated

Comment: Tested up to 1,000,000 (!!) coupons.

Comment: Thanks  Navnish Bhardwaj. I'll check that :)